# Encryption of the 'home' folder

Tags: encryption

How can I encrypt only the home folder? I do not want to enable the encryption from the installation procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this:
[How to encrypt your home folder](http://www.howtogeek.com/116032/how-to-encrypt-your-home-folder-after-installing-ubuntu/) ?

It's for ubuntu, but elementary is based on it so it should be exactly the same. :)